# Shared Custom AndroidJUnitRunner for multiple Android Library modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

##### Description

I'm trying to create a custom AndroidJUnitRunner that can be reused by multiple Android Library modules in my project for my Hilt Android tests so I don't have to keep creating a new one in each module.

##### Project Setup

I have a custom Android Library gradle config that is responsible for configuring everything related to Android.

`android-library-config.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

android {
    // android related configuration
}

// additional configuration that should apply to ALL android library modules
```

Then, every Android Library module applies this gradle config instead of defining its own configuration:

`some-feature-module/build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/android-library-config.gradle"

android {
    // additional setup if needed
}

dependencies {
    implementation projects.someLibraryInThisProject
}
```

#### Adding Hilt Android UI Tests to an Android Library module

Following the [Hilt testing documentation for instrumented tests](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#instrumented-tests):

> To use the Hilt test application in instrumented tests, you need to configure a new test runner. This makes Hilt work for all of the instrumented tests in your project. Perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a custom class that extends AndroidJUnitRunner in the
>    androidTest folder.
> 2. Override the newApplication function and pass in the name of the
>    generated Hilt test application.

With the following example in the `androidTest` directory:

```kotlin
// A custom runner to set up the instrumented application class for tests.
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

Then, we need to configure the new test runner in our gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.android.dagger.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

**However, I don't want to have to create a new `CustomTestRunner` for every Android Library module in my project. Instead, I want to create *one* and reference it *only* in my `android-library-config.gradle` so that it gets applied to each module that applies that config.**

#### What I've tried

I've tried introducing a new Android Library module, `:library:ui-testing:common`, and adding the custom test runner in its `androidTest` directory:

```
library
  └─ ui-testing
       └─ common
            └─ src
                 └─ androidTest
                      └─ java
                           └─ com.uitesting.common.CustomTestRunner
```

And then, updated my `android-library-config.gradle` to reference this new test runner:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.uitesting.common.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation projects.library.uiTesting.common
}
```

Since `:some-feature-module/build.gradle` applies `android-library-config.gradle` I expect my Instrumented tests defined in this module to use this new custom test runner. Instead, my tests just don't run. I get the following output:

```
Starting 0 tests on Pixel 3 - 10
```

I've also tried having `:some-feature-module` directly depend on `:library:ui-testing:common` and adding the following to `:some-feature-module/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.uitesting.common.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

and same result.

**I'm wondering if this is even possible since I haven't found any examples of this in the [official Android Instrumented test documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in order to make the custom instrumentation runner available for the build script to pick up is to place the runner in `main/` instead of `androidTest` of `:ui-testing:common`.

Then your feature module that is going to use the test runner should depend on `:ui-testing:common` directly as you described. (`implementation(project("..."))`)

You can also see [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/android-test/+/master:runner/android_junit_runner/java/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.java) that `AndroidJunitRunner` is placed in `java/...`  and not `javatests/...`.

Comment: if the custom test runner is defined in main/ how are we supposed to implement test runner dependecy? when I normally add implementation(androidx.test.runner) it does not work, apparently it needs to be androidTestImplementation(androidx.test.runner). But adding dependency with androidTestImplementation makes it not accessible in main/. Do you have any idea?